# Is there a way for two deferent themes to consume two different DB on a same WP instance?

Tags: database, sql

Before you downvote, yes I know there is a lot of similar questions around the web. But nothing touches my specific situation and how I should approach this problem.

I have a build a new theme for a website and got it up and running on different host and domain name. There I have all my new data that I need to move to old host as well as new theme.

My plan is to move both theme and db to old host. But the plan is to let the WP administrator to switch themes whenever he want it, but by switching themes I also mean switching data base.

Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: the database is the place where data are stored and the theme handles the data presentation. then you can switch theme with the same database. I am not sure to understand what you want to do, you can edit your question to add more details.

Comment: If by switch DB, you mean switch wp prefix (ie whole different set of tables), then in theory, yes you could since it's a variable.  The db name is a constant, so that not really so easy.   BUT realise that everything will change - the users etc.    One has to ask why you wouldn't just have an html page where he can choose one or the other, and share wp code?  eg share wp-content.  I do that for plugin development. I Run multiple wp, a nightly beta, a multisite, and they all use the same wp-content folder. See https://codex.wordpress.org/Editing_wp-config.php#Advanced_Options